# Why does dragging the middle mouse button sometimes translate my selection instead of rotating my view?

Tags: selection-tools, shortcut

I don't know what's causing this, but sometimes when I have faces or vertices selected in edit mode I will drag the middle mouse button to rotate my view but it will translate the selection instead. I don't press G or anything. Is there some Blender shortcut I'm not aware of that I'm activating by accident?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the mouse. The mouse might be faulty